# Is $Label equivalent to a global enumerated type?

Tags: customlabel, label

Is $label just the global accessor for custom labels? Or can we also use $label to access built in labels? For exmaple, on the email task layout there is a FROM field. Can we use $label.From to access that?

Also, how is $Label different from $label.site?

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation:

> A global merge field type to use when referencing a **custom label**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_label.htm

So no you cannot use it to reference the Object -> field label

To get the actual label of an object field you would use this

```
{!$ObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.fields.Quantity.label}
```

As for the $Label.Site

as per the documentation:

> A global merge field type to use when referencing a standard Sites
>   label in a Visualforce page. Like all standard labels, the text will
>   display based on the user’s language and locale.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_labelsite.htm

Basically is gives you access to the translated label for standard fields / messages for the Sites and the translations have already been done by Salesforce. 
This is needed because you cannot access the Site Objects fields like the example above for other sObjects